# Is there any packages to download landsat image by shapefile boundary in R or python?

Tags: python, r, remote-sensing, landsat, download

I want to find a package which can automatically download images within a predefined administration boundary (shapefile format). Does anyone know a package can conduct or simplify the process?

Comment: Do you know a certain site of service that delivers the Landsat imagery you would like to use?

Comment: @user30184 Yeah,there are many powerful and complicated web service providing download function, I want to seek a programable or easy warp api in R or python.

Comment: I only wanted to know from where do you want to download images. Like https://github.com/developmentseed/landsat-util/blob/develop/docs/overview.rst tells that images are searched from http://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/landsat/ and https://earthengine.google.org/.

Answer (score 3):

The "[landsat-util](https://github.com/developmentseed/landsat-util)" Python package used to support querying Landsat images based on a boundary defined by a shapefile until version 0.5.0, where it was removed to get rid of some dependencies. You could try using a version before that, e.g. v0.2.0. It's only a year old, so there is a chance it might still work.
The good news is that the package's devs are considering re-adding this feature in the future ([issue #91](https://github.com/developmentseed/landsat-util/issues/91)).

Comment: Thanks, I have seen landsat-util before and noticed the old version supported this feature. I will have a try.  And I can not help waiting for re-enabling the feature in the next version of landsat-util.

Comment: Unfortunately, I failed to install landsat-util v0.2.0. It seems that there are some error with compiling GDAL